# Remove ability view/list all table from schema

Tags: amazon-redshift

Using a Amazon Redshift database. I have a schema called 'Public', and another schema called 'SchemaX'. I have created a user called 'User1'; and give him access to 'SchemaX'. I want to stop 'User1' from viewing or listing the available tables in my 'Public' schema. How does one go about doing this?

Comment: sorry yeah I figured they were close enough but you're right.

Answer (score 0):

To disallow users from creating objects in the PUBLIC schema of a database, use the **REVOKE** command to remove that privilege.

```
REVOKE [ GRANT OPTION FOR ]
{ { SELECT | INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE | REFERENCES } [,...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
ON { [ TABLE ] table_name [, ...] | ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name [, ...] }
FROM { username | GROUP group_name | PUBLIC } [, ...]
[ CASCADE | RESTRICT ]
```

**SELECT**
Revokes the privilege to select data from a table or a view using a **SELECT** statement.

**INSERT**
Revokes the privilege to load data into a table using an **INSERT** statement or a COPY statement.

**UPDATE**
Revokes the privilege to update a table column using an **UPDATE** statement.

**DELETE**
Revokes the privilege to **delete** a data row from a table.

**REFERENCES**
Revokes the privilege to create a foreign key constraint. You should revoke this privilege on both the referenced table and the referencing table.

**ALL [ PRIVILEGES ]**
Revokes all available privileges at once from the specified user or group. The **PRIVILEGES** keyword is optional.

**ON [ TABLE ] table_name**
Revokes the specified privileges on a table or a view. The **TABLE** keyword is optional.

**ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name**
Revokes the specified privileges on all tables in the referenced schema.

**GROUP group_name**
Revokes the privileges from the specified user group.

**PUBLIC**
Revokes the specified privileges from all users. **PUBLIC** represents a group that always includes all users. An individual user's privileges consist of the sum of privileges granted to **PUBLIC**, privileges granted to any groups that the user belongs to, and any privileges granted to the user individually.

**CASCADE**
If a user holds a privilege with grant option and has granted the privilege to other users, the privileges held by those other users are dependent privileges. If the privilege or the grant option held by the first user is being revoked and dependent privileges exist, those dependent privileges are also revoked if **CASCADE** is specified; otherwise, the revoke action fails.

For example, if user A has granted a privilege with grant option to user B, and user B has granted the privilege to user C, user A can revoke the grant option from user B and use the CASCADE option to in turn revoke the privilege from user C.

**RESTRICT**
Revokes only those privileges that the user directly granted. This behavior is the default.